# How to embed a variable in a string that has quote marks using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I'm working on an ASP.Net Core 5.0 Razor Pages application. Users will see a list of pdf file names, by clicking on the file name they open their browser's pdf reader and they can view the pdf file.  the pdf files are stored in a sub folder of wwwroot.  (wwwroot > pdf)

If I run the code with a pdf file name hard coded, everything works as expected. If I run the code with the path and pdf file name as variable an error appears.

The attached code shows three examples of what I have tried. #1 This code with the file name (sample.pdf) hard coded works. #2 This code doe not work, the pdf container opens but the document does not.  #3 Code does not work, a Error 404.11 error appears, the pdf container does open.

Thanks in advance

Index.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace InfoBD.Pages.DocReader
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string fileLocation { get; set; }
        public void OnGet(string fileName)
        {
            //for testing fileName = sample
            fileName = "sample";
            
            var filePath = "/pdf/" + fileName + ".pdf";
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model InfoBD.Pages.DocReader.IndexModel
@{
}

<!-- web site where the example is found: https://pdfobject.com/ -->

<h1>PDF Viewer Sample</h1>
<div id="pdfContainer"></div>

<!-- set the size of te pdfviewer -->
<style>
    #pdfContainer {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 50rem;
        border: 1rem solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }
</style>


<script src="/lib/pdfobject.min.js"></script>

<!--  #1 the line of code below works -->
<script>PDFObject.embed("/pdf/sample.pdf", "#pdfContainer");</script>


<!--  #2 the line of code below does not work.  the pdf container opens but the document does not -->
@*<script>PDFObject.embed("/pdf/ + fileName + .pdf \",  "#pdfContainer");</script>*@


<!-- #3 the line of code below does not work even though filePath = /pdf/sample.pdf  -->
@*<script>PDFObject.embed("+filePath+", "#pdfContainer");</script>*@
```

Comment: `"/pdf/ + fileName + .pdf \"` This is being read as a string literal, `fullName` is not being concatenated

Comment: Interpolation might work well here.

Comment: Compare your C# code for filePath with your Razor #2, note the quotes

Comment: You should validate that the user should have access to the file so you don't allow a direct object access attack.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).  The basic gist is this :

```cs
@*<script>PDFObject.embed("/pdf/ + fileName + .pdf \",  "#pdfContainer");</script>*@
```

becomes this:

```cs
@*<script>PDFObject.embed($"/pdf/{fileName}.pdf \",  "#pdfContainer");</script>*@
```

Adding the `$` character at the beginning tells the interpreter that this is to be considered an interpolated string, and the `{}` escapes the variable name you want to interpolate into the string.

Comment: But then without the +

Comment: i modified 3# trying to use String Interpolation.   I get a green  and a message TS1005 (JS) ','  Any idea where the comma should be?  <!-- #3 the line of code below does not work even though filePath = /pdf/sample.pdf  -->
<script>PDFObject.embed($"/pdf/{FilePath}.pdf",  "#pdfContainer");</script>

Comment: @ATA I notice that you wrote `filePath=..` (lowercase f) and `{FilePath}` (upper case F). Those are different variables. Plus if filePath already contains that "/pdf/" folder, you probably don't want to add that again in "embed"

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly answering the question... this is more of a fix on the code that was given - Not sure your #3's `filePath` has any value within the page -- it's a local var in your method.  You want to set your property `fileLocation` and use that instead of `filePath` or `fileName`.

```cs
// Index.cshtml.cs
        public void OnGet(string fileName)
        {
            //for testing fileName = sample
            fileName = "sample";
            
            fileLocation = "/pdf/" + fileName + ".pdf";
        }


// Index.cshtml
@*<script>PDFObject.embed(fileLocation,  "#pdfContainer");</script>*@
```